# Why we need broadcast channel in the 3PC setting?

Tags: multiparty-computation

I am a MPC learner for privacy-preserving machine learning. Recently, I am reading this paper: [FLASH: Fast and Robust Framework for Privacy-preserving Machine Learning](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1365.pdf). I am confused about the question that why we need broadcast channel in the 3PC setting. I guess that is because consensus, but I am not sure. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is the paper you are reading in the malicious model without aborts? if so, I think your guess is correct.

Comment: @AntonioFa Thank you. I see.